# Can't print log or hit a breakpoint after fork in subprocess using android studio

Tags: android, c, android-studio

After fork I can't print any log or hit a breakpoint in sub process. But there is no problem with using waitpid in main process. Thanks for your help.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_suihong_listenuninstall_MainActivity_init
  (JNIEnv *, jobject)
{
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0)
  {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "test", "this is child");
    sleep(60);
  }
  else if(pid > 0)
  {
    //signal(SIGCHLD, test);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "test", "this is parent");
    int staus;

    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "test", "child is exits");
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "test", __FUNCTION__);
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ad. logging:**

After reading a lot of Android NDK code and trying to wrap my head around unix file descriptors and pseudo terminals, using logcat with **No Filters** did the trick for me.

I had been using Android Studio's logcat with the *"Show only selected application"* filter set, which filtered out my child process log statements.